# Moving up the stack of fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to add an home up button at the action bar, when my activity has 2 fragments:

but it seems that it doesnt add my first fragment to the stack, since i get a log of "count entry:0"

```
public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        Fragment fragment = this;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login,
                    container, false);

            TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.signUpText1);
            tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
                    ft.hide(fragment);
                    ft.add(R.id.container, new SignupFragment());
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class SignupFragment extends Fragment {

        public SignupFragment() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View signupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup,
                    container, false);

            ActionBar ab = getActivity().getActionBar();
            ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
            ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

            return signupView;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

            Log.e("LoginActivity", "count entry:" + fm.getBackStackEntryCount());
            if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                // fm.popBackStack();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

How to properly add a fragment to a back stack (is it possible?)
Thank you and sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify the path you go with your fragments?
From your Question I understand that you have the PlaceholderFragment and from there you move on to the SignupFragment? Right?
Since your first Fragment (PlaceholderFragment) gets initialized that way

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

i think you dont add this fragment to the backstack so clearly the backstack is empty. replace with.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .addToBackStack("optionalName").commit();
}
```

I think that should solve it.

EDIT:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        Log.e("LoginActivity", "count entry:" + fm.getBackStackEntryCount());
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            // fm.popBackStack();
        }
        break;
```

Here you are using SupportFragmentManager, on top you are using FragmentManager, those are diffrent and can't be mixed, you stick to either one. If you want to support low api devices below api 11 use SupportFragmentManager, if not stick to FragmentManager.

Since you add both Fragments to FragmentManager, the SupportFragmentManager backstack remains empty.

Best Regards

Comment: The activity shows the PlaceholderFragment, that has a button that adds an SignupFragment. 
I did what u suggested but it didn't helped, it still shows like the backStack is empty. "count entry:0"

Comment: you alSo use diffrent fragment managers fragmentmanager and support fragment manager you should only use one of em if you are supporting only high api you shouöd use fragment manager